Counting number of separate events in dataframe
I am trying to count the number of separate events in a Dataframe (not number of occurences)
Let's say i have this dataframe :
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1], columns=["events"])

And i want to count the number of separate events.
If i use
df.value_counts()

It' going to give me the number of occurences of each event :
events
1         6
2         4
Name: count, dtype: int64.

But i want to count the number of separate events regardless of their lenght.
The result should be something like this :
     events
1         3
2         2

I wanted to know if there is a built in function for this.
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Note that your example seems incorrect. But in any case you want to use this kind of grouping.

Craft a mask (with shift and ne) to remove the successive duplicates and value_counts:
df.loc[df['events'].ne(df['events'].shift()), 'events'].value_counts()

Output:
events
1    3
2    2
Name: count, dtype: int64


Method 1 :
df['events'].to_numpy():
This converts the events column of the DataFrame to a NumPy array.
It allows us to work with the data in a NumPy array format, which is index-agnostic.
This means that operations performed on this array are not affected by the DataFrame's index.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1], columns=["events"], 
                  index=[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
                  )

a = df['events'].to_numpy()[:-1]
b = df['events'].to_numpy()[1:]
c = df['events'].to_numpy()
changes = np.concatenate(([True], a != b) )
print(changes)

separate_events_count = pd.Series(changes).groupby(c).sum().astype(int)
print(separate_events_count) 
'''
1    3
2    2
dtype: int32
'''

Method 2 :
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1], columns=["events"])

a = df['events']
b = df['events'].shift()

res = a.ne(b).groupby(a).sum().astype(int)
print(res)
'''
events
1    3
2    2
Name: events, dtype: int32
'''


Added an explanation. Please check it. Thank you @mozway
